# Linker problems in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, linker

after upgrading to Ubuntu 11.10, I've found that many of my old and current developments can't be compiled anymore. I've reduced the problem to a simple example:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

int main() {
    Display* display = XOpenDisplay(":0.0");
    XCloseDisplay(display);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling it using:

```
g++ -lX11 test.cpp
```

or

```
g++ -c -o test.o test.cpp
g++ -lX11 -o test test.o
```

Causes a failure to happen:

```
/tmp/ccBAOpzy.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
test.cpp:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `XCloseDisplay'
```

Any ideas? I've found that some linker stuff has changed in 11.10:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NattyNarwhal/ToolchainTransition

But still doesn't explain these problems.

Comment: You should have installed the X11 dev package libx11-dev before.

Comment: @boto I know that. Actually, the problem was in the parameter order. Ubuntu 11.10 ships GCC 4.6.1, which apparently introduces stricter parameter ordering constraints. g++ test.cpp -lX11 works fine.

Comment: Now let's see how I can make SCons work around that...

Comment: To all those saying that the problem is in libx11-dev not being installed, please read carefully the error message: it doesn't complain about libX11 not existing.

Comment: I believe the documentation has always been quite clear on insisting that `-l` options need to be last on the command line. Anyhow, if you solved the problem yourself, post and accept your solution so this question is no longer flagged as unsolved.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> `g++ -lX11 -o test test.o`

Above command is *incorrect*. Try this instead:

```
g++ test.o -lX11
```

Explanation of why the order matters [here](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).

Also, you should never call your executables `test` on UNIX.

Comment: Calling an executable `test` is ok *if* (a) you don't have `.` in your `$PATH`, and (b) you invoke it as `./test` rather than `test`.

Comment: But if it does get on the PATH, shell scripts you've never heard of will start exploding around you and your machine will never be the same again. Actually, most shells have a built-in named test, and many scripts prefer to use `[` these days, so it might be that nothing happens .... maybe.

Comment: If using make, can set CC, CFLAGS, LDFLAGS, and LDLIBS.  LDLIBS=-lX11 in this case does the right thing, so "foo: foo.o"  becomes: `cc foo.o -lX11 -o foo`